# Text not placed properly when using float:right

Tags: html

I'm having an issue when trying to use float:right in an <"h3">

I'll post my code under, with a screenshot of the result. The code is 100% similar to the placement that actually works. Sorry for asking this weird question, as I don't really know how to ask it.

```
    <header><h3>Fredag 4. januar 2019</h3><h3 style='float:right'>Varmmat i kiosk Fredag: </h3></header>        <header>
    <h3 id='ct'></h3>
    <h3 style='float:right'>Nachos - 30kr</<h3>     </header>
```

[picture of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PG5D.png)

as you can see, the "Nachos - 30kr" is not all the way to the right. And the code is exactly the same as "Varmmat i kiosk Fredag:".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need a _verifiable code example_ that reproduce the issue you describe, and in its present state it doesn't.

Comment: @LGSon How do I do this? :)

Comment: @Jesper Post your actual HTML example where the results equal the screenshot so we can recreate the issue.

Comment: @Scath This representation should be enough.. I don't see how the rest of the code should matter?

Comment: As the code you posted doesn't represent the image dump, it is not enough, so if you want help, post a sample that reproduce that, or else the only thing you will get is a bunch of guesses.

Comment: Note the typo in your code; you never close the final `<h3>`: Change `</<h3>` to `</h3>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you might want to align the text to the right as well:

```
<h3 style='float:right;text-align:right;'>
```

Can you need to clear floats on your header:

```
header { clear: both; }
```

Comment: You need to clear your floats after as part of `<header>` like `header { clear: both; }`

Comment: @diodeus-james-macfarlane This worked perfectly! Thanks! :))

Comment: I'll close this.